# How to set Dom Storage Enabled is TRUE with webview_flutter

Tags: flutter, webview, webview-flutter

I has problem with DomStorageEnabled [webview_flutter], i can't set command: settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);

I has been implement website React JS and use cookies, Local Storage, How to enable in webview_flutter?

Thanks you.

Comment: Please read the documentation of the tools your using before posting on stackoverflow.

Comment: Thank you for comment, i have got it.

Comment: @AnhTrung how did you find this?? I'm facing a similar problem.